# How can I programmatically unbind IPv6 from a network interface on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-7, group-policy, scripting

I need to unbind the IPv6 services from a number of client workstations running Windows 7. ("Untick" the selected box in the screenclip below.)

[image]

For what it matters, they currently all have a single, wired network interface, which should make things easier.  To clarify, I do not want to [disable IPv6 on the systems as a whole](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929852), just unbind it from the currently used interface.

Although there exists a [PowerShell v4 cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/jj130872(v=wps.630).aspx) that would do this, it's a command that's limited by OS version as well as PowerShell version (and will not work on Windows 7).

I'm open to really any suggestion that would work, short of doing it manually. We have SCCM in our environment, the machines are domain-joined, and I make regular use of the SysInternals suite, which seems to open up basically every possible approach I can think of (I'm not even above a run-once VBS script, or similar "icky" solutions), but my Google-fu has failed me on how to pull this off.

Comment: Get to scripting: http://eniackb.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-2008.html

Comment: What do you expect to achieve by unticking the box? What lead you to think that unchecking that box has the effect of removing the binding?

Comment: It might be simpler and more realistic to simply control v6 traffic rather than remove the ability to manage it.

Comment: @JimB well, my primary reason for believing that the IPv6 binding to a given NIC is toggled by that checkbox is that Microsoft says so (in one of the articles I linked, even... among many places), but personal experience also informs me that they're correct, so there's that too. And, not for nothing, but this *is* controlling IPv6 traffic.  No IPv6 traffic will be created on the NICs where the IPv6 binding is removed, controlling where IPv6 traffic originates from (or not, as the case may be).

Comment: See this old list of issues if you unbind the nic (https://windorks.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/known-issues-with-disabling-or-unbinding-ipv6/) this is an old list, I believe its now longer.  It will unbind the protocol, but that doesn't stop the network stack apparently.  You did see the warning "From Microsoft's perspective, IPv6 is a mandatory part of the Windows operating system and it is enabled and included in standard Windows service and application testing" I'm being sarcastic because almost no one clicks the link to read what happens if you do this.

Comment: Last but not least NDIS binding removal behavior in this case I believe is implemented as an NDIS filter since v4 and v6 use the same stack ( I can't find anyone to confirm or deny that but it explains the host of v6 issues that occur).  So my recommendation is to control v6 by ensuring that v6 packets go nowhere and do nothing by assigning a ULA prefix, preferring v4, and disabling 6to4 (if you have public IP's) This will prevent any malware that uses v6 from communicating.